# Evaluate Line Integral over a curve

Tags: integration, line-integrals

I am working the following question:

> **Question as given:**
>
> Evaluate the line integral $\int_{C}cos(z)dx + e^{x}dy + e^{y}dz$,  where $C$ is the curve parameterized as $C(t)=(1,t,e^{t}), 0 \leq t
>  \leq 2$.

I have got the following result but I'm not sure if this is correct or if I have made a mistake somewhere?

$\begin{aligned}
\int_0^2 cos(e^t)\cdot 0 + e^{1} + e^t \cdot e^t dt &= \int_0^2 e + e^{2t} dt \\
&= \int_0^2 e dt + \int_0^2 e^{2t} dt \\
&= \left[te\right]_0^2 + \left[\frac{e^{2t}}{2}\right]_0^2\\
&= 2e + \frac{e^4}{2}-\frac{1}{2}\\
&= 32.2356.
\end{aligned}$

Comment: Looks good to me. Why do you suspect you have a mistake?

Comment: @Dylan_Carlo_Beck for the number of marks available I would expect to need to do more work than this and I have a big lack of belief in my own abilities so was sure I had gone wrong somewhere!  Thank you for looking it over!

Comment: Sure thing. Have more faith in yourself!